# Как добавить Tab-вкладки, где содержимое не Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, tab, вкладки

Есть две activity.
1 - в которой listview.

```
public class TopList extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_list);


        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(TopList.this, ListInner.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        };

        ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_options);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener); 

....
```

и вторая - в которой ViewPager:

```
public class MyClass extends FragmentActivity {


    static int PAGE_COUNT = 10;

    ViewPager pager;
    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_myclass);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pagermy);
        pagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

}

...
```

Их нужно сделать содержимым двух вкладок.

С помощью устаревшего способа:

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab);


        // получаем TabHost
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();


        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Первая вкладка");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, MyClass.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

        tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
        tabSpec.setIndicator("Вторая вкладка");
        tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, TopList.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    }
}
```

работает все практически как надо, за исключением того, что в активити с Listview  табы оказываются над ActionBar.

Однако это устаревший метод, а как надо делать по современному и по правильному?Или же как исправить, чтобы табы были под ActionBar.